# How to use shared_ptr and custom reference counting simultaneously?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reference-counting

I have a legacy class whose lifetime is managed by reference counting (it derives from ACE_Event_Handler, to be precise).

I want to be able to manage it using std::shared_ptr in my code but still keep the old legacy reference counting (objects of the class need to be accessed by a third-party library that doesn't accept shared_ptr - ACE, to be precise).

An object must be deleted when the reference count drops to 0 and all of the shared_ptr instances managing it get destroyed.

I have only one idea: keep an instance of shared_ptr pointing to the object until the reference count drops to 0 and then reset it. Somehow, this feel dirty. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not write a smart pointer which handles incrementing and decrementing the ACE reference count, and use that?  It's easy enough.

Comment: I'd like to use std::shared_ptr.

Comment: Something like [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) seems like a better fit than `std::shared_ptr`.  If boost isn't an option, then rolling your own `instrusive_ptr`-like class is probably your only option.

Comment: I read about it and even thought of formulating the question as using intrusive_ptr and shared_ptr simultaneously. It looks like I need to use either std::shared_ptr or intrusive_ptr throughout all of my code and I prefer the former.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use shared_ptr?  This feels like an X-Y problem.

Comment: My team was handed over a big project. We get a lot of memory-related bug reports (leaks and segmentation faults). Fixing them is very hard - the code is too complex and we aren't even the ones whom the original developers handed the project over.
So I decided to introduce smart pointers everyehere possible. I am too deep in this refactoring to back up or introduce a custom smart pointer, hence my insistence on smart_ptr. The classes that I recently figured out to be managed by ACE are not isolated - some ot their base classes already require to be managed by shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach would be to have your own custom ptr implementation with `ACE_Event_Handler::add_ref()` in the constructor and `ACE_Event_Handler::release()` in the destructor.

Alternatively, you can use `std::unqiue_ptr` with **custom** deleter:

```
template<typename T>
struct custom_releaser
{
    void operator()(T *p) { if (p) p->release(); }
};

std::unique_ptr<T, custom_releaser<T>> my_ptr;
```

If you **really** want `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = std::shared_ptr(std::move(my_ptr));
```

I wonder, however, if it will properly call `ACE_Event_Handler::add_ref()`. I guess, `std::shared_ptr` will ref count based on it's own member variable - so that you would need to provide a method to do `ACE_Event_Handler::add_ref()` when creating an instance and adding ref counts.